# Adding a number to a column with a value in it Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Ok So I have A column with a count IIF expressions As shown:

```
UNTESTED: Count(IIf([TEST]="UNTESTED",1))
```

What I want to do is now look at where the location was and when the test was done and if in a specific location and YEAR then add 8 to that value I am now trying to use:

```
UNTESTED: Count(IIf([TEST]="UNTESTED",1)) AND IIf([REGION]="CANADA" And [YEAR]<=2012,[UNTESTED]+8,[UNTESTED])
```

Thanks in advance if you can solve this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to my question, I solved it :

```
IIf([Site]="CANADA" Or [Site]="ALASKA",IIf([Year]<"2013",Count(IIf([Pass_Fail]="UNTESTED",1))+8,
Count(IIf([Pass_Fail]="UNTESTED",1))),Count(IIf([Pass_Fail]="UNTESTED",1)))
```